# d3.js tweening text animation not working after selectAll with data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I'm attempting to create a ticker style increasing value text transition in d3.js for a label on a doughnut graph. The doughnut graph works correctly, and the labels work if i'm not using "data" and "enter, but as i've moved to a more advanced version I can't get the transition to work anymore

Would somebody be able to explain why the below doesn't work, but just applying as .text() without a transition does apply the value?

```
var text = svg.select(".labels").selectAll("text")
                .data(pie(data), key);

        text.enter()
            .append("svg:text")
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .attr("class", "text-label")
            .transition()
            .tween("text", function(d) {
                console.log(d);
                console.log(this.textContent);
                var i = d3.interpolate(0, d.data.value),
                    prec = (d.value + "").split("."),
                    round = (prec.length > 1) ? Math.pow(10, prec[1].length) : 1;

                return function(t) {
                    this.textContent = (Math.round(i(t) * round) / round) + '%';
                };
            });
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: First of all, the function(t){...} on the bottom of your code need to return a value. Your function do not return any. It would be better if you can post your html or svg result of executing the code.

Answer (score 0):

try changing this line 
prec = (d.value + "").split(".")
to
prec = (d.data.value + "").split(".")